# c# getting values from using loop like combobox[i], i++

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Hello i am working on some personal project, 
I have lots of comboboxes in my project, which names are combobox1,combobox2 etc..
What i am trying to do is, getting combobox.text values respectively and do some work according to this.

Here is my code below;

```
  for (i = 1; i <= geneList.Length; i++)
        {

            baserequest = "/" + comboBox[i].Text + ".docx";
            sources.Add(new Source(new WmlDocument(basesource + geneList[i] + baserequest), false));
baserequest="";
            DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, Path.Combine(tempDi.FullName, "Output.docx"));

        }
```

so that actually not work. I searched but i think i missearching something because all i can get is about iterating through items, but what i want to do is exactly this;

> comboBox[i].Text

Thank you very much.

Comment: If your comboboxes are named comboBox1, comboBox2 .... then you can't refer to comboBox2 using a sintax like comboBox[2]. This syntax means .. give me the third combobox stored in an array of comboboxes tht contains at least 3 elements.

Comment: So what can i do, it works if i wrote like    
baserequest = "/" + comboBox1.Text + ".docx";
but its not a optimized solution. I have to write this couple lines for every comboboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your comboboxes are named `comboBox1`, `comboBox2` .... then you can't refer to comboBox2 using a syntax like `comboBox[2]`. This syntax means .. *give me the third combobox stored in an array of comboboxes* (and that should contain at least 3 elements)

So if you really want to use this syntax you need to create that combobox array somewhere in your code. After the call to `InitializeComponent` for example

```
public class Form1: Form
{
     // declare the array as a global variable 
     private ComboBox[] combobox;

     public Form1()
     {
         // Create and initialize all the elements of your form 
         // according to the properties set in the WinForms Designer
         InitializeComponent();

         // Choose all the individual comboboxes that you want to use
         // inside your loops in the remainder of your code
         combobox = new ComboBox[] { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };
     }

     // all the code of your Form1 follows.....
}
```

A final note: You use a different array to create your loops. This array is named `geneList` and it should be kept in sync with the combobox array. Meaning the two arrays should have the same number of elements otherwise (if the geneList array is bigger than the combobox one you will get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException). Also array indexing start at index 0 not 1 so the usual loop is created with this syntax

```
for (i = 0; i < geneList.Length; i++)
```

Otherwise if you start from 1, as you do now, you skip the first element in the array and the last loop searches for an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve. It actually seems work :)

Comment: Beware. You use a different array to loop over named _geneList_ and you start the loop from index 1. This could be very dangerous if the combobox array and the geneList one are not kept in sync (meaning the geneList array should be 1 bigger than the combobox array)